# Calculating mean coverage per gene

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, bioinformatics

I have 2 files:
file 1 (below) has bp start and stop coordinates

| Chrom | Gene start (bp) | Gene end (bp) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50902700 | 50902978 |
| 1 | 103817769 | 103828355 |

file 2 has mean coverage values per base pair position:

| Chrom | pos | mean |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12141 | 0.029005 |
| 1 | 12142 | 0.029216 |

what I need: I need to match chrom, start and end from file 1 (taking start and end as a range) to chrom, pos; and calculate average of means (mean column in file 2) within that range of coordinates of file 1.

desired output:
Chromosome/scaffold name    Gene start (bp) Gene end (bp)   average coverage per gene

| Chrom | Gene start (bp) | Gene end (bp) | average of means |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50902700 | 50902978 | (mean coverage for this gene) |
| 1 | 103817769 | 103828355 | (mean coverage for this gene) |

I have tried using dictionaries  and nested for loops:

Code:

```
`# importing gene start/end files
df_gene = pd.read_csv('gene_list.csv')
# importing exome data file
df_data = pd.read_csv('exomes.coverage.summary.tsv', sep = '\t')
# Creating a Dictionary to store mean values
dict_mean=df_data.set_index('pos')['mean'].to_dict()

start = df_gene['Gene start (bp)'].to_list()
end = df_gene['Gene end (bp)'].to_list()

list_mean=[]
x=0
df_mean = pd.DataFrame(columns=['start','end','mean coverage'])
### looping:
for s,e in zip(start,end):    
    for key,val in dict_mean.items():
        if key>=s and key<=e:
                list_mean.append(val)
                x=np.mean(list_mean)    #calculating average of means           
                
    my_series = pd.Series(data=[s, e, x], index=['start', 'end', 'mean coverage'])
    df_mean=df_mean.append(my_series,ignore_index=True)
    
### Add mean coverage to gene dataframe
df_gene['mean coverage'] = df_mean['mean coverage']

df_gene.to_csv('gene_out.csv', index=False)
`
```

The code works, but it doesn't account for the chrom number. How can I find the average of means within the range of start and stop?

Comment: Hello, welcome to SO. I'm afraid I don't know enough about biology/bioinformatics to understand the question. Could you describe more clearly what are the operations you want to perform, and what 'coverage' represents ?

Comment: the tables are incomplete, there's more data points, I'm trying take 'chrom', 'start' and 'end' as a range and find an average of the means from file 2 (file 2 has means for individual points within the range)   P.S: Coverage stands for how well "sequenced" that position is. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the code you've tried and describe how it didn't work for you. See [ask].

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem. It is very dependent on having consistent data, meaning that every entry `(chrom, pos)` in file 2 has a corresponding `(chrom, s, e)` in file 1. If it is not the case, you'll have to perform additional checks in the inner `while` loop.

```
# importing gene start/end files
df_gene = pd.read_csv('gene_list.csv')
# importing exome data file
df_data = pd.read_csv('exomes.coverage.summary.tsv', sep = '\t')
# Creating a Dictionary to store mean values
chroms_f2 = df_data.['Chrom'].to_list()
positions = df_data.['pos'].to_list()
means = df_data.['mean'].to_list()
f2_as_list = sorted(zip(chroms_f2, zip(positions, means))

starts = df_gene['Gene start (bp)'].to_list()
ends = df_gene['Gene end (bp)'].to_list()
chroms_f1 = df_gene['Chrom'].to_list()
f1_as_list = sorted(zip(chroms_f1, zip(starts, ends)))

df_mean = pd.DataFrame(columns=['chrom', 'start','end','mean coverage'])

### looping:
i1 = 0
c1, (s, e) = f1_as_list[i1]
list_mean = []
for c2, (p, m) in f2_as_list:
    if not (c1 == c2 and s <= p <= e):
        my_series = pd.Series(
            data=[c, s, e, np.mean(list_mean)], 
            index=['chrom', 'start', 'end', 'mean coverage']
        )
        df_mean=df_mean.append(my_series,ignore_index=True)
        list_mean = []
    while not (c1 == c2 and s <= p <= e):
        i1 += 1
        c1, (s, e) = f1_as_list[i1]
    list_mean.append(m)
    
### Add mean coverage to gene dataframe
df_gene['mean coverage'] = df_mean['mean coverage']

df_gene.to_csv('gene_out.csv', index=False)
```